# touchesMoved within restraints?

Tags: ios, swift, touchesbegan

I've got view that I'm dragging on the screen.  My touches began/moved/ended code works until I try to keep the view from not going any higher than when it starts out.

The endgoal effect is I'm wanting the user to be able to drag a `UIImageView` that is like 100pixels above a textview ontop of the textview, and once the "`touchesEnded`" is called it'll animate back to its original position and run appropriate code if the user dropped it on the text field.

I know in theory how to code all of that, I just can't get the actual movement to work.

To keep the view from ever going higher than where it starts out, I tried:

```
 override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: self.superview)
        if position.y >= originalY // calculated in touches began with  originalY = self.center.x  {
        self.center = CGPoint(x: originalX, y: position.y)

}
```

But that creates some weird side effects where I click and drag down. The view stays where it's at, and it's only until after the view makes it down past my textfield/ other buttons near the top of the screen that it snaps to my position and starts scrolling up and down.

Any ideas how to only let my view's Y
 be moved up to where it started out and down to a certain point without all these weird behaviors?

Edit:

I got rid of the if check on the Y and the dragging worked as expected, but once I made it down below my textfield/buttons area up top, when I'm doing my touchesEnding and resetting my X and Y back up to the top, my view stops just below the textfield/buttons. So it looks like for some reason my view is getting hung up on other elements on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

#### Reverse `y`

Note that `y` is `0` at the top of a `view` and `height` at the bottom. Take this into account when making constraints on `y`. Print `position` at `touchesDidMove:` for more insight.

#### Subviews

Other `subviews` might steal your `touchEvents`. Implement `touchesCancelled(with:)` for more insight, and make sure that your movable views are in front of other `views`

If other `subviews` takes the `touchEvents`, when the touch returns to your `view` it will trigger `touchesBegan(with:)` again, and will offset your `origin`.